# Compare 2 percentage value using if statement

Tags: linux, shell-script, scripting

First of all, I am new here so If I make any mistake, I am sorry for that.
This is my first question here.

I am writing a script to copy logs files for a product based on Linux.
I have completed the copy part, however I want that script must verify the /var partition size before copy logs.

Below is the part of script which is giving me an error.

I want that if /var partition size is less than 80%, it must copy the logs or else it must exit.

```
size=`df -kh | grep var | awk '{print $5}'` #output is 1%, so it must execute other statements.

echo var partion $size utilized

if (( "$size" <= 79% ))

then

        echo "/var partition is less than 80%"

else

exit

        echo "/var partition is more than 79%"

fi
```

**Output of script**

```
[root@manage home]# sh logcopy.sh 
var partion 1% utilized
logcopy.sh: line 19: ((: 1% <= 79% : syntax error: operand expected (error token is "<= 79% ")
```

---

**Out of awk command and df -kh**

```
[root@manage home]# df -kh | grep var | awk '{print $5}'
1%
[root@manage home]# df -kh
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda6             980M  642M  287M  70% /
/dev/sda1              95M   25M   65M  28% /boot
/dev/sda9             6.0G 1004K  5.7G   1% /home
/dev/sda7             4.6G  879M  3.5G  20% /usr/local
/dev/sda8             446G  2.7G  421G   1% /var
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The percent sign is the modulo operator (e.g. `8 % 5` is `3`), it's expecting the second operand for it. The error would be similar if you had used `(( size <= 79% ))` and you'd get the same error for the right-hand side if `size` itself didn't contain a percent sign.

So, let's remove the percent sign from the input

```
size=$(df -kh | awk '$6 == "/var" {print $5}')
size=${size%"%"}
if (( size < 80 )); then
    echo "/var is less than 80 % full"
fi
```

Here, `${size%"%"}` is the suffix-removing expansion `${var%word}`, the first `%` is part of the syntax, the second (quoted) is the `%` we want to remove. The quotes are here because `${var%%word}` is similar, removing the longest matching suffix instead of the shortest. We could also use `${size%%%}` but that's more confusing to read.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of running `df` for all your disks you can specify the target (`df /var`)

For GNU/Linux the output can be formatted.
Finally you can omit `%` with `tr`, `sed substitution`,...

```
df /var --output=pcent | tail -1 |tr -d '%'
55
```

Just if you want to use `awk` over `df` output better use with `df -P` to make it portable.
If the disk pathes are too long then maybe you will not get the output in one line like:

```
df -kh
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol00
                      3.9G  404M  3.3G  11% /
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol05
                      3.9G  442M  3.3G  12% /home
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol04
                      3.9G  261M  3.5G   7% /var
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol03
                      3.9G  137M  3.6G   4% /tmp
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol02
                      7.8G  3.6G  3.8G  49% /usr
```